# filter data from azure data storage in data factory v2

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory v2. We have a table in a Azure data storage and I am able to load all data in a Azure SQL database by using the copy data option.

But what I would like to achieve is filter the data in the data storage by the field status that is an integer field. I tried some examples from the Microsoft website. But every time I get the bad syntax error when I run the pipeline. 
So what I tried is, in the source tab I choose my data store as source data set, with the source table documentStatus. And I clicked on use query and put this line in:
"azureTableSourceQuery": "$$Text.Format('Status = 2')" 
But when I run this I get this error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Can anybody help me with writing a correct query so I can filter my source on this status field?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set `"azureTableSourceQuery": "Status eq 2"`:

[image]

Please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#supported-comparison-operators) related to Azure Table Storage Filter Sql.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  It's so simple but I didn't know how to start. This solved my issue!